# How Bring layout1 below layout 2 programmatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to bring the whole content of linearlayout1 below linearlayout2 in java code. How do I do that?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            tools:context="com.example.examplepro.MainActivity" >

1--------> <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_weight="50" >    
           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:text="1"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
          </LinearLayout>
 2------> <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_weight="50"> 

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:text="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
              <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:text="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can try with `mainLayout.removeView(ll1);` and then `mainLayout.addView(ll1);`. Not sure, though. just a try

Comment: cool. I added as an answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the linear layout 1 first, and add it again.

As the parent layout is of vertical orientation, it should add Linearlayout 1 below LinearLayout 2.

```
mainLayout.removeView(ll1); 
mainLayout.addView(ll1);
```

Hope this helps.